# Hacking a PIR Sensor

Tags: pir

My end goal here is to launch a camera strapped to outside of the payload of a High Altitude Balloon to take pictures at 5 second intervals during ascent and descent. Trying out a few ideas, I've bought a trail camera ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W6VJQ5P)). It's triggered by a PIR sensor, which isn't really what I want, and I'd rather it just take a picture ever 5 seconds period. The whole situation has to last for about 3-5 hours on batteries.

So having provided that context, and to reduce my question to the simplest form I can think of, is there a well-known way to induce a PIR sensor to trigger "constantly"? First prize goes to "non-invasive" techniques for doing this. I have an Arduino in system but I'm trying to make the camera function of this little project, to the extent possible, independent and off-the-shelf.

Comment: Just find the PIR output that indicates a trigger, look at the "triggered" voltage level, remove the PIR sensor and set a voltage on that line equivalent to the voltage level measured previously.

Comment: is the sensor sensitive to TV remote control signal?

Comment: You might be better off getting a cheap, lightweight, weather-sealed "sports" camera with built-in time-lapse, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/COOAU-Microphone-Stabilization-Underwater-Accessories/dp/B07DWP3M46/ref=sr_1_4 (sorry, I have not used that device myself, and just mention it as an example.)

Comment: If the camera doesn't have a time-lapse mode, and you don't want to hack into it, then build a simple battery-powered timer with a 555 to flash an infrared LED on, for a few seconds, every 5 minutes. If that doesn't trigger the PIR sensor, use a dual 555 and send a sequence of pulses instead of a single pulse. Experiment to find what works. Tape your little trigger circuit onto the camera so the IR LED shines toward the PIR.